# How do I switch slider on certain checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, php, select, slider, var

I have a checkbox to check for 'koop' or 'huur'

```
<li class="content-visible">
              <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fff">Koop of huur</a>
              <div class="cd-faq-content" style="display: block">
                <div class="checkbox ">
                  <input id="koophuurgarage" name="garages" class="styled" value="koop" type="checkbox" <?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['garage']) && ($_REQUEST['garage']=='koop' ||  (is_array($_REQUEST['garage']) &&  in_array('koop',$_REQUEST['garage']))))?'checked':'';?>>
                  <label for="checkbox1" value="koop">Koop</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox ">
                  <input id="koophuurgarage" name="garages" class="styled" value="huur" type="checkbox" <?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['garage']) && ($_REQUEST['garage']=='huur' || (is_array($_REQUEST['garage']) && in_array('huur',$_REQUEST['garage']))))?'checked':'';?>>
                  <label for="checkbox2" value="huur">Huur</label>
                </div>                                    
              </div> <!-- cd-faq-content -->
            </li>
```

Then a price slider with simple JS.

```
   <li class="content-visible">
              <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fff">Prijs per maand</a>
              <div class="cd-faq-content" style="display: block">
                <input id="prijsslider_garage_huur" class="irs-hidden-input" readonly="" type="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="min_prijs" id="min_prijs" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['max_prijs'])) echo trim($_GET['max_prijs']); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="max_prijs" id="max_prijs" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['max_prijs'])) echo trim($_GET['max_prijs']); ?>">
              </div> <!-- cd-faq-content -->
            </li>  

            <li class="content-visible">
              <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fff">Prijs per maand</a>
              <div class="cd-faq-content" style="display: block">
                <input id="prijsslider_garage_koop" class="irs-hidden-input" readonly="" type="hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="min_prijs" id="min_prijs" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['max_prijs'])) echo trim($_GET['max_prijs']); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="max_prijs" id="max_prijs" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['max_prijs'])) echo trim($_GET['max_prijs']); ?>">
              </div> <!-- cd-faq-content -->
            </li>
```

How can I select that if value is 'koop' it only shows that specific slider, and when 'huur' is selected only shows that slider?

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far? We're glad to help, but we don't write code for you.

Comment: I have tried to set a check for the input id to be checked and then display the matching slider, doesnt work at all.

Comment: I meant the code you tried, maybe you need to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask